# Put different values in a map and write to excel using POI using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, apache-poi

I want to put different values in a map and write them in an excel file using POI libraries. I have two questions and it would be great if someone can answer them

1) I want to put different values at different stages in a map and write them in different columns of the excel. for eg. at page 1, I have a value A which I want to put in the map and at page 2, I have a value B and C which I want to put into the map. I want to write these values in excel at different columns.

2) I may be visiting page 1 and 2 again and at that time I would want these values A and B to be written in a new ROW. How can I increment the row and write these values in a new Row everytime, I visit page 1 and 2 again.

I have written something like,

```
    Map<String, Object[]> putdatainMap;
String orderid=driver.findElement(By.id("ORDER_ID")).getAttribute("value");
        putdatainMap.put(orderid, ?)//This I get from page1

String txnid=driver.findElement(By.name("TXN_ID").getAttribute("value");
       putdatainMap.put(txnid,?)//I don't want to lose the orderid which I got earlier, rather I want to put the orderid and txnid in different columns)

String status=driver.findElement(By.id("status").getAttribute("value");
       putdatainMap.put(status,?)//The txn id and status I get from page2
```

Now I want to write the above values in an excel file and do something, that when I restart this flow the new values should come in a new Row.

```
Set <String> keyset = putdatainMap.keySet();
        int rownum = 0;
        for (String key : keyset)
        {
            Row row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
            Object [] objArr = data.get(key);
            int cellnum = 0;
            for (Object obj : objArr)
            {
               Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);
               if(obj instanceof String)
                    cell.setCellValue((String)obj);
                else if(obj instanceof Integer)
                    cell.setCellValue((Integer)obj);
            }
        }
        try
        {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(filepath +"/"+filename+".xlsx"));
            workbook.write(out);
            out.close();
            System.out.println("Data written to drive sucessfully");
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Store your last row number and in next iteration, start writing from last row number + 1